# Trouble to compile a native c++ program in 64 bits

Tags: c++, visual-studio, 64-bit

I try to compile a native Visual Studio 2008 C++ program in 64 bits on my windows 32 bits.

I have an error during the link because the version of `msvcprtd.lib` in 64 bits is not found.

```
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP90.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

I have installed the last version of *Microsoft Windows SDK* but I can't found the *msvcprtd.lib* file in x64 directory.

Comment: Why would you want to cross compile for debug, when you're not allowed to redistribute the debug DLLs?

Comment: I have the same trouble in release...

Answer (score 1):

This error is likely due to not having the library directories set up to reference the x64 ones. This can easily happen if you add a new x64 configuration to a project. The simplest solution is to create a new solution with project for both win32 and x64 and then look at the VC++ Directories/Library Directories in the project properties, and ensure the ones you have in your project are the same.

Answer (score 0):

msvcprtd.lib doesn't appear in my latest SDK in either 32 or 64 bits. I do see it in version 5.0 of the SDK though, but only for the IA64 platform type.

Perhaps that lib simply doesn't exist. Try removing it from the list of lib's you're linking against and see what errors you get then, googling those errors may lead you to the name of the lib you actually want to link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Go to your project property -> Configuration Manager and then create a configuration manager which specifies x64 as platform and set it as active.

Answer (score 0):

My short answer is did you make sure you have the cross complier installed.  I remember going crazy when trying to compiled a 64 bit binary on my 32 bit XP, when I realized I did not have the cross compiler installed. (Having my Visual studio media handy is helpful).

Also as Madhur said make sure your Configuration is set for 64 bit.